# open a map and the camera goes to my position without clicking any button or any marker

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

```
private GoogleMap mMap;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps_ciudad_sales);

    // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
    SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
            .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
}


/**
 * Manipulates the map once available.
 * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
 * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
 * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
 * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
 * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
 * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
 */
@Override
public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap;


    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NORMAL);
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_SATELLITE);
    googleMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_TERRAIN);

    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-19.047696, -65.260062),15));
    // Add a marker in Sydney and move the camera
    LatLng sucre = new LatLng(-19.047696, -65.260062);
    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sucre).title("Berlin"));
    mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sucre));
}
}
```

I tried lot of things but nothing works so far so I put this as an example but I really want is to open the mapsactivity and the camera zoom and goes to your actual position without clicking anything or making marks....

Comment: You question is a little bit unclear. What exactly do you mean by your actual position? Your current location or the lat/lng coordinates?

Answer (score 0):

I used this code in my app to show current location in map at first. After that you can drag the pointer `imageMarker` around and you will get the changed location reflected in the map.

```html
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@android:color/white"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/container_toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView android:gravity="center_vertical"
                android:id="@+id/Locality"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_btn_current_location"
                android:drawableStart="@drawable/ic_btn_current_location"
                android:drawablePadding="20dp"
                android:ellipsize="end"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:text="@string/click_to_change_loc" />


        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/container_toolbar">

 

        <com.google.android.gms.maps.MapView
            android:id="@+id/map"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/locationMarker"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="30dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="30dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/locationMarkertext"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/rounded_corner_map"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingLeft="2dp"
                android:paddingRight="2dp"
                android:text="@string/fetch_loc"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imageMarker"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:src="@drawable/add_marker" />
        </LinearLayout>



    </FrameLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

```css
public class FetchAddressIntentService extends IntentService {
    private static final String TAG = "FetchAddressIS";
    protected ResultReceiver mReceiver;
    public FetchAddressIntentService() {
        super(TAG);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        String errorMessage = "";

        mReceiver = intent.getParcelableExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RECEIVER);

        if (mReceiver == null) {
            Log.wtf(TAG, "No receiver received. There is nowhere to send the results.");
            return;
        }

        Location location = intent.getParcelableExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA);

        if (location == null) {
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_location_data_provided);
            Log.wtf(TAG, errorMessage);
            deliverResultToReceiver(AppUtils.LocationConstants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage, null);
            return;
        }

        Geocoder geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        List<Address> addresses = null;
        String result = null;

        try {

            addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(location.getLatitude(),location.getLongitude(),1);

        } catch (IOException ioException) {
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.service_not_available);
            //Log.e(TAG, errorMessage, ioException);
            try {
                LatLng newLatLng = new LatLng(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                String latlngStr = String.valueOf(newLatLng.latitude)+","+String.valueOf(newLatLng.longitude);
                String googleapiurl = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=" + latlngStr + "&sensor=true";
                Log.e("sammy_error_googleapi", googleapiurl);
                Log.e("sammy_error_location", newLatLng.toString());
                Log.e("sammy_error_latitude", String.valueOf(newLatLng.latitude));
                Log.e("sammy_error_longitude", String.valueOf(newLatLng.longitude));
                HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(googleapiurl);
                HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

                HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                InputStream stream = entity.getContent();
                int b;
                while ((b = stream.read()) != -1) {
                    stringBuilder.append((char) b);
                }

                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(stringBuilder.toString());
                if (jsonObject.getString("status").equals("OK")) {
                    JSONArray array = jsonObject.getJSONArray("results");
                    for(int i=0;i<array.length();i++){
                        JSONObject obj = array.getJSONObject(0);
                        result = obj.getString("formatted_address");
                        String regex = "null\\b\\s*";
                        result = result.replaceAll(regex,"");
                        System.out.println("myaddress " + result);
                    }
                    deliverResultToReceiver(AppUtils.LocationConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT, result, null);

                }

            } catch (ClientProtocolException cpe) {
                Log.e("TAG", "ClientProtocolException", cpe);
            } catch (IOException ioe) {
                Log.e("TAG", "IOException", ioe);
            }catch (JSONException jsone) {
                Log.e("TAG", "JSONException", jsone);
            }
        } catch (IllegalArgumentException illegalArgumentException) {
            errorMessage = getString(R.string.invalid_lat_long_used);
            Log.e(TAG, errorMessage + ". " +"Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +", Longitude = " + location.getLongitude(), illegalArgumentException);
        }

        if (addresses == null || addresses.size() == 0) {
            if (errorMessage.isEmpty()) {
                errorMessage = getString(R.string.no_address_found);
                Log.e(TAG, errorMessage);
            }
            deliverResultToReceiver(AppUtils.LocationConstants.FAILURE_RESULT, errorMessage, null);
        } else {
            Address address = addresses.get(0);
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++) {
                sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i)).append(" ");
            }
            sb.append(address.getLocality()).append(" ");
            sb.append(address.getPostalCode()).append(" ");
            sb.append(address.getCountryName());
            result = sb.toString();
            String regex = "null\\b\\s*";
            result = result.replaceAll(regex,"");
            Log.e("TAG", "GEOCODE_RESULT "+result);
            deliverResultToReceiver(AppUtils.LocationConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT, result, address);

        }
    }

    /**
     * Sends a resultCode and message to the receiver.
     */
    private void deliverResultToReceiver(int resultCode, String message, Address address) {
        try {
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RESULT_DATA_KEY, message);

                if(address!=null){
                    bundle.putString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_AREA, address.getSubLocality());
                    bundle.putString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_CITY, address.getLocality());
                    bundle.putString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_STREET, address.getAddressLine(0));
                }

                mReceiver.send(resultCode, bundle);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

```html
public class MapLocation extends Fragment implements OnMapReadyCallback, GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener, LocationListener {


    private MapView mMapView;
    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private final static int PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST = 9000;
    private static final Integer LOC_PERM = 0x1;
    private static String TAG = "MAP LOCATION";
    private TextView mLocationMarkerText, mLocationText;
    private LatLng mCenterLatLong;
    private AddressResultReceiver mResultReceiver;
    protected String mAddressOutput, mAreaOutput, mCityOutput, mStreetOutput;
    private String addressStr, latStr, lngStr, userid;
    private static final int REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE = 1;

    


    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.maplocation, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity)getActivity()).setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ((AppCompatActivity) getActivity()).getSupportActionBar().setTitle("MY LOCATION");

       

       

        if (getActivity() != null) {
            mMapView = (MapView) view.findViewById(R.id.map);
            mMapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        }

        try {
            MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mMapView.getMapAsync(this);

        mLocationMarkerText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.locationMarkertext);
        mLocationText = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.Locality);

        mLocationText.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

                openAutocompleteActivity();

            }


        });

        mResultReceiver = new AddressResultReceiver(new Handler());

        if (checkPlayServices()) {

            if (!AppUtils.isLocationEnabled(getActivity())) {

                final AlertDialog.Builder dialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity());
                dialog.setMessage("Location not enabled!");
                dialog.setPositiveButton("Open location settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        Intent myIntent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                        startActivity(myIntent);
                    }
                });
                dialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface paramDialogInterface, int paramInt) {
                        paramDialogInterface.dismiss();
                    }
                });
                dialog.show();
            }
            buildGoogleApiClient();
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Location not supported in this device", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        Log.d(TAG, "OnMapReady");
        if (mMapView != null)
            mMap = googleMap;

        mMap.setOnCameraChangeListener(new GoogleMap.OnCameraChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onCameraChange(CameraPosition cameraPosition) {
                Log.d("Camera postion change" + "", cameraPosition + "");
                mCenterLatLong = cameraPosition.target;


                mMap.clear();

                try {

                    Location mLocation = new Location("");
                    mLocation.setLatitude(mCenterLatLong.latitude);
                    mLocation.setLongitude(mCenterLatLong.longitude);

                    latStr = String.valueOf(mCenterLatLong.latitude);
                    lngStr = String.valueOf(mCenterLatLong.longitude);
                    Log.e("sammy_onMapReady", "LAT: " + latStr + " LNG: " + lngStr);
                    startIntentService(mLocation);
                    //mLocationMarkerText.setText("Lat : " + mCenterLatLong.latitude + "," + "Long : " + mCenterLatLong.longitude);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle) {
        System.out.println("sammy_onConnected");
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        Location mLastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            System.out.println("sammy_onConnected_loc "+latStr+" "+lngStr);
            changeMap(mLastLocation);

        } else
            try {
                LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        try {
            LocationRequest mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
            mLocationRequest.setInterval(10000);
            mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(5000);
            mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        Log.i(TAG, "Connection suspended");
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        try {
            if (location != null)
                changeMap(location);
            LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.removeLocationUpdates(
                    mGoogleApiClient, this);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

    }


    protected synchronized void buildGoogleApiClient() {
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(getActivity())
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        try {
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
            mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        }
    }

    private boolean checkPlayServices() {
        int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(getActivity());
        if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
            if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
                GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, getActivity(),
                        PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
            } else {

            }
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }

    private void changeMap(Location location) {

        System.out.println("sammy_reached_changeMap");

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(getActivity(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }

        if (mMap != null) {
            mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
            LatLng latLong;

           

        
                double latitude = Double.parseDouble(lat_);
                double longitude = Double.parseDouble(lang_);
                latLong = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
                Location location1 = new Location("");
                location1.setLatitude(latLong.latitude);
                location1.setLongitude(latLong.longitude);

                CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                        .target(latLong).zoom(19f).tilt(70).build();

                mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
                mMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));

                latStr = String.valueOf(location1.getLatitude());
                lngStr = String.valueOf(location1.getLongitude());
                Log.e("sammy_changeMap","LAT: "+latStr+" LNG: "+lngStr);
                startIntentService(location1);

           


        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Sorry! unable to create maps", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

    }

    class AddressResultReceiver extends ResultReceiver {
        public AddressResultReceiver(Handler handler) {
            super(handler);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onReceiveResult(int resultCode, Bundle resultData) {

            if (resultCode == AppUtils.LocationConstants.SUCCESS_RESULT) {

                System.out.println("sammy_reached_onReceiveResult");
                Log.e("sammy","reached_onReceiveResult");

                mAddressOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RESULT_DATA_KEY);

                mAreaOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_AREA);

                mCityOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_CITY);
                mStreetOutput = resultData.getString(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_STREET);

                Log.e("sammy","address "+mAddressOutput+" area "+mAreaOutput+" city "+mCityOutput+" state "+mStreetOutput);

                try {

                    addressStr = new LinkedHashSet<String> (Arrays.asList(mAddressOutput.split(" "))).toString().replaceAll("(^\\[|\\]$)", "").replace(", ", " ");

                    mLocationMarkerText.setText(addressStr);

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }


            }


        }

    }

   

   


    protected void startIntentService(Location mLocation) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), FetchAddressIntentService.class);
        intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.RECEIVER, mResultReceiver);
        intent.putExtra(AppUtils.LocationConstants.LOCATION_DATA_EXTRA, mLocation);
        getActivity().startService(intent);
    }


   

   

    

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }



    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }


}
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but what I want to do is that every time I travel to some place the camera takes me to the place im in..... with out placing a LatLang specific...

Comment: No problem. The original code was written to do exactly what you want. Try to implement this code and run it. When I'll get time I'll upload a code for auto pointer change also.@GUTI

Answer (score 0):

Google Maps provides no public methods to access the current location.
To zoom into the current location you first need to get the current location. The best way to do it is by using Google Location Services.

Layout File(Nothing special just a layout with a map fragment):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="abhishek.shopbill.activities.MapsActivity">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

The Activity code( I have nested all the callbacks for better understanding the flow):

```
    public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        //Step1: find the map fragment.
        final SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        //Step 2: configure the GoogleApiClient. This is used for location services.
        if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(new GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
                            //Step 3: After the GoogleApiClient is connected get the Map.
                            mapFragment.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
                                @Override
                                public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
                                    try {
                                        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
                                    } catch (SecurityException e) {
                                        //no permissions granted
                                        e.printStackTrace();
                                    }

                                    //Step 4: Get the current location(Check the getLastLocation
                                    //method at the bottom)
                                    Location selectedLocation = getLastLocation();

                                    //Step 5(Last): Animate the map to the postion
                                    if (selectedLocation != null) {
                                        //Zoom in and animate the camera.
                                        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
                                                .target(new LatLng(selectedLocation.getLatitude(), selectedLocation.getLongitude()))
                                                .zoom(17).build();
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


                                        //only zoom in don't animate
                                        /*googleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(new LatLng(selectedLocation.getLatitude(), selectedLocation.getLongitude())));
                                        googleMap.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.zoomTo(17));*/

                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        }

                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
                            //Connection suspended code here.
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(new GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
                            //connection failed code here
                        }
                    })
                    .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                    .build();
        }
        //Don't forget to connect the GoogleApiClient
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    public Location getLastLocation() {
        //Check for permission first
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return null;
        }

        //using the FusedLocationApi get the last location
        Location lastLocation = LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);

        return lastLocation;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        //Don't forget to disconnect
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onDestroy();
    }
}
```

Have a nice day..

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will try it!

Comment: Hello! I have something in my mind and I dont know if that can be done.... I have a Listview and I want that every line takes to the same mapactivity (done) but different locations... (not done) can you helpe me please

Answer (score 0):

Your question not clear, but this line of code

```
 mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngZoom(new LatLng(-19.047696, -65.260062),15));
```

in the onMapReady Callback should work well.

Comment: sorry, Im new programing what I want to do is when I click a button takes me to a mapactivity and the camera shows the place Im at right away... if I put a marker or LatLng direction it takes me to another to a specific place but if I travel my location would be different.....